# how to show search results page in an overlay not a new tab?

Tags: asp.net, forms, search

I need to display the search results page in an overlay. now when I submit the search button I lost focus on my site and the results open on a new page. how can I show results overlay?

```
   <form action="https://google.com/search" method="get" class="form-inline d-flex justify-content- 
    center md-form form-sm active-cyan active-cyan-2 mt-2">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="site:www.forexample.com" />
    <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control form-control-sm ml-3 w-75" />
    <a onclick="this.closest('form').submit();return false;"></a>
   </form>
```